# Angular 2 and jQuery - how to test?

Tags: jquery, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, angular2-testing

I am using Angular-CLI (webpack version) for my Angular 2 project and I also need to use jQuery (sadly. In my case, it's a dependency of Semantic-UI and I am using it for handling menu dropdowns).

The way I am using it:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then listing in it `angular-cli.json` file in the `scripts` array:

```
scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

So it gets included into bundle file and this file is automatically used to root html file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js">`

Then `declare var $: any;` in files where I need it and it works well.

However there is a problem with `ng test` tests, as Karma throws an error `$ is not defined`.

Comment: How did you include jQuery in your component spec? I'm getting the same error and tried to include jQuery via the files array in karma.conf.js.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because the testing html file, provided by Karma, doesn't include the `scripts.bundle.js` file as normally served version does.

The solution is easy; you just include same path to the jquery file into `karma.config.js` file in project's root folder. This file is available at the root of the project.

In `files` array, add the path with `watched` flag like this:

```
files: [
  { pattern: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: false },    
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
]
```

Karma now should know about the jQuery dependency.

Comment: Oh gosh, that was one step away from what i was trying to do for 2 days, I just removed "included" flag from the same line, and it worked!

Comment: when i use this code  jQuery('#confirmDialogModal').modal('hide');, I get modal is not a function error while running test cases, but in real application it works. also jQuery('#facilityIdModalButton').click(); doesnt throw any throw while running test cases. any idea how to fix or skip jquery calls