# How to unit test Angular 6 component that uses Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular6

```
import $ from "jquery";
let newobject = $.extend(true, {}, object);
```

> Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

At some point in my Angular 6 application those lines of code execute in my component when I execute ng test. I couldn't find how to make the testing framework know where it can find the library. I am using Karma and Jasmine.

I have read the angular.io documentation, tried typings, tried referencing jquery through angular.json file, tried to use the karma-jasmine-jquery library modifying the karma.conf.js file, and also tried @types/jquery. I also considered to get rid of that way of cloning an object but since this could be helpful for someone else in some other situation I dared to ask.

I am using jquery 3.3.1 installed in node_modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 and jQuery - how to test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013155/angular-2-and-jquery-how-to-test)

Comment: I did saw that before publishing but it didn't do the trick for me. Ask if you think you need more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions from the post that cgTag mentioned but it didn't quite help me, what did the trick was to replace

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

for

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

I hope it helps someone else. Don't forget to still [Import jquery to karma configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013155/angular-2-and-jquery-how-to-test)